# How to change focus from treeview node to control using c#?

Tags: c#

A form will opens when i click on treenode. I need to set focus from treenode to the textbox control in newly opened form.

Comment: Just `yourTextBox.Focus()`. Have you tried it?

Answer (score 1):

Use the

```
form.Activate()
```

method on the new form to bring it to the front, then use the

```
textbox.Focus()
```

method on your textbox.

Comment: it is'nt working. The focus is still there in tree node

Comment: @Prathapsv that probably means you have something else happening (event with handler changing focus, a modal form somewhere, some other `Focus()` call elsewhere...)

Comment: @Prathap sv Can you provide us with some additional information or code samples of some sort?

Comment: I have tried debugging but i could'nt find a solution. tvMenus_NodeMouseClick event { teDepartment f2 = new Department(); f2.TopLevel = false; f2.Parent = splitContainer1.Panel2; f2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill; f2.Show(); f2.Activate(); f2.BringToFront(); } in department form load event { ActiveControl = txtName; txtName.Focus(); }

Answer (score 1):

You could try to set the ActiveControl property on the desired TextBox upon opening the newly created form: [Active Control MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.containercontrol.activecontrol%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Basically, you do sth like this in your load form method:

```
private void yourFormLoad(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ActiveControl = yourTextBox;
}
```

Of course, you have to firstly focus the new form by calling the form Activate method:

```
yourForm.Activate()
```

Comment: I am using splitcontainer control and i've placed a treeview control in panel1 of splitcontainer. when i click on tree node a form 'll opens (eg: employee) in panel2 of splitcontainer.The problem is the focus is not moving to textbox control in employee form from treeview selected node.I have written                       this.Activate();
ActiveControl = txtName;
txtName.Focus();                                                   in form load event, but still it is not working

Comment: Try calling Activate on the click event of the tree node, just after creating the form. Also, I suggest debugging a little to see how the events are triggered, when the load form method is hit, what happens before that, etc.

Comment: still the problem persists

Comment: the focus is still there in treenode

Comment: As I mentioned earlier, you should try to debug a little and maybe you'll manage to understand why the behavior persists

Comment: I have tried debugging but i could'nt find a solution. tvMenus_NodeMouseClick event                                       { teDepartment f2 = new Department();                                   f2.TopLevel = false;
                        f2.Parent = splitContainer1.Panel2;
                        f2.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
                        f2.Show();
                        f2.Activate();
                        f2.BringToFront();    }                                              in department form load event {  ActiveControl = txtName;
            txtName.Focus(); }

Comment: Maybe you could also try to force focus removal from the tree view. You could set its ActiveControl property to null before moving focus to the form